# Not hidable columns in GXT Grids

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am looking for a method to prevent a user from hiding certain columns in my grids. I was trying to override `Menu createContextMenu(final int colIndex)` method of `GridView` where I find the submenu items that are related to my not-hidable columns and call `disable()` on them:

```
...
for (Component menuItem : menu.getItems()) {
    String text = ((MenuItem) menuItem).getText();
    if (((MenuItem) menuItem).getSubMenu() != null && (text.equals("Columns"))) {
        for (Component subMenuItem : ((MenuItem) menuItem).getSubMenu().getItems()) {
            String subMenuItemText = ((MenuItem) subMenuItem).getText();
            if (<i want this column to be not hidable>) {
                subMenuItem.disable();
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

It almost works - when the grid is just rendered the menu items that I disabled are greyed out and they don't accept user's input. However it all breaks after some other, not disabled columns are toggled. All of a sudden the disabled menu items become enabled.

I am using GXT 2.2.6.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is found. Any changes in columns call GXT listeners and eventually restrictMenu method of GridView is called. This overrides all my disable settings. The solution is to add custom listener let GXT' listener do its job and then overwrite the enable/disable settings.